# Android connect bluetooth L2CAP device(PS4 Controller), how to do through root?

Tags: android, bluetooth, l2cap

I try to connect my phone to a L2CAP device (PS4 Controller), that uses L2CAP as bluetooth connection protocol.

Documentation of DualShock 4 controller: http://www.psdevwiki.com/ps4/DS4-BT

Android officially does not support L2CAP anymore. Since android 4+ they 'hide' it. (but can still be found everywhere in the source code)

Source:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-6.0.1_r31/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.java

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html

But as I read on the Internet, it cannot be called, only trough root.

Does anyone know if it can be done with BlueDroid? Or have an example about how to do it with root?

This is impossible, because it will not allow calling a function in another package ->

```
 mSocket = new BluetoothSocket(BluetoothSocket.TYPE_L2CAP, -1, true, true, this, 2, null);
```

Any help or guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: Hey man, I know this is delayed but did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Pfoei I spent many hours on it, and got closer and closer.. After a while I ended up on an ubuntu machine, working with BlueZ to trigger L2CAP connection to the device.. I did get a connection to the controller, and they are paired for a short time, cause the controller itself showed the connected lights and I could read some data, but after 200ms or so the connection dropped.. Seems Im missing some kind of key or sending wrong requests... So short answer, no :(

Comment: Some useful links -> 

DS4 controller doc ->http://www.psdevwiki.com/ps4/DS4-BT

Android 6.0 bluetooth input -> https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-6.0.1_r31/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothInputDevice.java


Android bluetoothStack -> https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/master/stack/l2cap/l2c_api.c

Comment: Thanks anyways bud. Appreciate the response.